# Royal Enfield Bullet Electra Headlight Replacement

Tags: motorcycle, headlight, royal-enfield

I have a Royal-Enfield Bullet Electra 350 model 2017. The headlights are dim.

Can I replace my motor cycle head lights with classic 350 head light?

The Electra 350 uses 35/35 Watt bulbs but the classic uses 60/55 Watt bulbs. Can I replace the Electra headlight bulb?

I have heard that there will be wiring problem if I change bulbs - is it so?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use the correct wattage, your bulb will blow. RE is not known for good electrical. It's better to stay away from replacing the main bulb. I would suggest you to have aux lights. You'll have to plug an extra relay for that.

Answer (score 1):

Both Electra and Classic 350 has same electrical system i.e 12 V DC and both hosts a 12 v 8Ah battery however Electra has **12V, HS1- 35/35 W** halogen lamp while Classic 350 has **12V, H4-60/55W**  halogen.As pointed out by @Ghost You can not upgrade to classic bulb due to change in wattage however you can opt for 35 W LED or HID lamps as they are brighter and more efficient in that way and there are plenty of them available. You can also check this link http://www.bull-leds.in/